# Aggregation value inside array of array elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i have json structure like this:

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'result': [{
        "score": 0.0,
        "result_rules": [{
                "rule_id": "sr-1",
            },
            {
                "rule_id": "sr-2",
            }
        ]
    }]
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'result': [{
        "score": 0.0,
        "result_rules": [{
                "rule_id": "sr-1",
            },
            {
                "rule_id": "sr-4",
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

i want to count `rule_id`, so the result would be:

```
[
    {
        'rule_id': 'sr-1',
        'doc_count': 2
    },
    {
        'rule_id': 'sr-2',
        'doc_count': 1
    },
    {
        'rule_id': 'sr-4',
        'doc_count': 1
    }
]
```

i've tried something like this, but it's showing empty aggregation

```
{
    "aggs":{
        "group_by_rule_id":{
            "terms":{
                "field": "result.result_rules.rule_id.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For aggregation on nested structure you would have to use nested aggregation.

See the example on ES [DOC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

Comment: thank you the query is success but i want to add some filter for example ```result.result_rules.status:true```, how do i perform it? @anand

Comment: you can combine the nested aggregation  with filter see the example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: i've got an error ```named_object_not_found_exception: unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name```

Comment: the query looks like this http://myjson.com/d3o7m and the error is :```unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name [group_by_rule_id]: parser not found```

Comment: i've fixed it, misplaced second aggs did that error